# CodeIgniter, Accessing class property after page reloads, is it possible?

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, properties

I have a CI page that will load to a div in view file, using jQuery. Using switch(page_parameter), I control what is showing from the page.

When I call the page for 3rd time, I set a value to the class array.
But when I call the 4th time, the array become empty.

I was wondering, is it actually possible to use the class property to store value that can be used after page re-access? Or something missing in my head? 
I know that using session is not a good idea, since the real array is a big chunk of serialized xml.

Here's my code:

```
class MyClass extends MY_Controller
{
    public static $pitems = array();

    function Hotel(){
        parent::MY_Controller();
    }

   function new_campaign(){
        $params = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();
        switch($params['step']){
             case '3' : self::$pitems = array("test","another"); //here the class array was set successfully
                        $this->load->view('viewer');
                        break;
             case '4' : print_r(self::$pitems); //here the array is empty
                        break;

        }
   }
```

In the viewer page, there's a call to the page:

```
   <a href="myclass/new_campaign/step/4">Next page</a>
```

Same issue also with $this-> 
What am i missing here?
Thanks in advance~

edit:
I saw a script that has similar scenario. it successfully reused the variable set in the constructor, instead of treating it as a class variable. i'll look thorough to confirm this, but for now, i'll close this thread. Thanks Chris for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not really sure what your trying to do but I have users jQuery post()/get()/ajax() many of times in CI and have had no problems. So despite not knowing or understanding what your trying to do. I thought I'd at least say I know loading data without refresh in CI through something like jQuery isn't an issue. Example on system I built on CI had a twitter like feed of tweets where jQuery on a timer was polling for new data and coming back with it each time accordingly if something new was to be shown.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes, i have no issue with loading the page with jquery. I'm trying to set the class variable from one of the case in the function and getting the same (changed) variable the next load of the page. SOmehow, that variable is reset on the page load (which is empty...) Hope this helps...

Comment: I saw a script that has similar scenario. it successfully reused the variable set in the constructor, instead of treating it as a class variable. i'll look thorough to confirm this, but for now, i'll close this thread. Thanks Chris for sharing.